# Why is the term "point" not defined in topology? What are the elements of the open sets of the topology? What are the UR-elements of the open sets?

Tags: general-topology

I looked in several books on topology: Munkres, Schaum's, etc. and cannot find a definition for the word "point". Why is the term "point" not defined in topology? What are the elements of the open sets of the topology?  What are the UR-elements of the open sets?

Comment: have you had a course in set theory/logic?

Comment: A topological space is in particular defined as a *set* together with (some other stuff); the formal mathematical definition of "set" is where we get a notion of point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory

Comment: You're right, in a way: "point" is not defined in geometry; "point" is a primitive term; but Euclid defined a point as "that which has no part" (if memory serves me correctly.) That's gotta be confusing; but there it is.

Comment: Yeah, all I meant is that the term point is so basic, maybe that's why they don't define it explicitly in topology in particular.

Comment: I know a bit about set theory and logic; but I want to know more. See my other comment.

Comment: Hmmm.... My other comment does not display. I'll post it again.

Comment: I had classes in set theory, abstract algebra, and logic; but no class in topology. I have been studying on my own lately. I am interested in the "space of all formal languages" as a dynamical system. A metric is hard or impossible to find, so I went to topology for "nearness". It seems to me if we base topology on sets, and sets are collections of elements (sometimes points), then we should know about points or our foundation is uncertain.

Comment: We say that $x$ is a point of the space $X$ (which happens to be defined as a set with perhaps additional properties) if $x\in X$. -- So "point" is just an alias for "element" whenever the sets we discuss are space-y

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen: That helps me a bit. I forgot there is an original set (X) with elements, and the topology is a subset of the power set of X. I guess the definition of the points must depend on X; but the topological properties may be independent of the points in X. It still seems like the properties of the points of X might have some bearing on the topology, though. Again, thanks for the response. Having people to converse with about math is an exciting prospect.

Answer (score 3):

Any set $X$ can be given a topology. For instance, $\wp(X)$ is a topology on $X$. So is $\{\varnothing,X\}$. So is $\{X\setminus F:F\subseteq X\text{ is finite}\}$. The elements of $X$ can be anything: ordinal numbers, ordered $n$-tuples of real numbers, functions from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R$, sequences of sets of complex numbers — you name it.

When we construct a specific space, we specify the underlying set, and the elements of that set become the points of the space.

Comment: So these points in the topology satisfy certain axioms or properties? I think there must be at least a little more. I am just beginning to think about the Space of All Formal Languages as a dynamical system, and algebra, randomness and topology come into play. I have taken a few classes on abstract algebra (not that I'm very good at it; but I have some ideas about the subject) but I have never taken a course on topology. I am cracking the books on it now. I am also interested in "neighborhood semantics" and accessibility in modal logic, though that will be along journey for me.

Comment: @JoeCash: Not really. A topological space is an ordered pair $\langle X,\tau\rangle$, where $X$ can be any set at all. The structural requirements are on the topology $\tau$: we require that $\varnothing,X\in\tau$, that $U\cap V\in\tau$ whenever $U,V\in\tau$, and that $\bigcup\mathscr{U}\in\tau$ whenever $\mathscr{U}\subseteq\tau$. In other words, $\tau$ contains the empty set and the set $X$ itself, is closed under taking finite intersections, and is closed under taking arbitrary unions.

Answer (score 0):

The point-set topology is the basic or general topology its really the study of the most basic ideas like when can a topology on a space be derived from a metric.

The ideas of continuity, dimension, compactness, and connectedness rely on the ideas of interior, closure, and boundary, so are not really defined in terms of points.

[http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/Top/TopNotes.pdf](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/Top/TopNotes.pdf) has some good notes if you want to read on.

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. It's difficult to study math alone. It's a language, and I need to converse about it to get fluent, and that requires a little more than "rubber duck troubleshooting". I'm still leery of the idea that there are foundations of topology that we haven't defined. Maybe we don't analyze any deeper than the open sets; but those open sets have elements/points that will be of some concern. Again, thank you for your responses.

Comment: @JoeCash There is no problem with the foundations. As others have tried to make clear, topology is built upon the notion of open/closed subsets and the very definition of subsets involves the elements, a.k.a. points, of sets. So yes, topology uses points, but they are just not the main point of interest

Comment: @NDewolf: Thank you for your response; but I still think what you're saying is that we don't need to know what the elements of the open sets are. Aren't there any limitations to what can be a point in an open set in a topology? There must be, I think. Can the open sets be pure sets? I suppose they can, as I think pure sets can satisfy the axioms for a topology; but are pure sets all we're allowed to use? No, I am sure that's not the case. Can the open sets have ANY kind of elements, or are there restrictions on what can be an element of an open set in a topology?

Comment: @JoeCash Since in general point-set topology starts from ZFC, there is only one notion of set and hence of element. Outside ZFC I'm not sure (it's definitely not my field), but I guess people will have looked at it. Another possibility is "pointless topology", aka the theory of locales, which starts from the categorical duality between topologies and frames. Here the notion of point is of no real importance (and it contains ordinary topology).